# Sentence boundary detection in splitta: definition of feature 1

Tags: python, split, nlp

In the Python [splitta](https://github.com/hinstitute/splitta/blob/master/SETUP.rst) code (the sentence boundary detection tool by Dan Gillick, described [here](http://www.dgillick.com/resource/sbd_naacl_2009.pdf)), I don't understand the nature of feature 1 which is defined as *"w1: word that includes a period"*. When I trace the value of feature 1 for several examples, the result is always *{'w1': '.'}*

Does someone can explain to me the nature of this feature?